# I want to do 2 things after a "then" statement in a "if.. then.. else" statement

Tags: list, ocaml

```
let rec filtersList2fromList1 (List1:string list) (List2:string list) : string list =  
 let finalList = [] in  
 match List1 with  
 | s :: tl -> if List.mem s List2 = true   
 then finalList @ [s] else filtersList2fromList1 tl List2  
        | [] -> []
```

so that,

```
filtersList2fromList1 ["x";"y";"z"] ["z";"x"] would be ["x";"z"]  
filtersList2fromList1 ["x";"y";"z"] ["x"] would be ["x"]
```

what I would like to add is, if the "if" statement is true, not only it would execute "finalList @ [s]", but also "filtersList2fromList1 tl List2" so that it will be a recursion. Without executing "filtersList2fromList1 tl List2" when it is true,

`filtersList2fromList1 ["x";"y";"z"] ["z";"x"]` would only be `["x"]`, which is wrong.

How should I solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the definition of dolls_of?

Comment: Why are you creating `finalList`?  It's doing absolutely nothing.  Keep in mind that lists are immutable, so `finalList @ [s]` doesn't change the value of `finalList` but returns a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you'd either use a semi-colon or a `let...in` construct.  In your case, neither will do what you want however.

You should read through the documentation on the standard library, as the `List` module contains everything you need to do what you want:

```
let filterList2fromList1 list1 list2 =
  List.filter (fun x -> List.mem x list2) list1
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that since you mentioned recursion, I'm assuming that when you wrote `dolls_of` you meant `filtersList2fromList1`. Also I'm assuming that `List1` and `List2` are supposed to be `list1` and `list2`, since the former would be an error.

It should also be pointed out that `@` is an `O(n)` operation and it is not recommended to use it to build up lists. However as Niki pointed out in the comments, your use of `finalList` is pointless, so you don't actually need `@` anyway.

To answer your question: You can execute two expressions after another by separating them with a `;`. However `dolls_of` is a function without side effects, so executing it without doing anything with its result would make little sense.

What you actually want to do, as far as I can tell, is:

```
if List.mem s list2   
then s :: filtersList2fromList1 tl list2
else filtersList2fromList1 tl list2
```